# Accidentally gave inaccurate information regarding my notice period in a phone interview

Tags: interviewing, mistakes

During a phone interview I was nervous and mistakenly told the interviewer that I was currently serving my notice period, however it actually finished one month ago. Is this likely to cause a problem and if so how can I communicate the correct information to the potential employer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: I've edited your question to try and make it a bit clearer, hopefully it still matches what you were trying to ask but feel free to roll it back if I've gotten it wrong!

Comment: If you finished your notice one month ago, that means you have been unemployed for a month?

Answer (score 7):

Just contact them an tell them the great news that you are available sooner than you thought.

Comment: And with the benefit of having a valid excuse to keep the communication channel open :)

Answer (score 2):

**Don't panic!**

Assuming you would like to start sooner than the date you gave them on the phone interview (and/or you think being available sooner would be advantageous to your application) then e-mail or phone the contact who has been handling your application (hiring manager/recruiter etc) and let them know that you have an update to your availability and you are now free to start on x date instead.

As Daniel mentions in his answer they will probably see this as good news and there's nothing to worry about.